# $|2x|+4>0$, solve for all x

Tags: inequality

$|2x|+4>0$

I can see that it is true for R, but solving in cases, I'm having some difficulty.

$|2x|+4>0$

$|2x|> -4 $

So, $2x > -4$ or $-2x > -4$

$\implies x> -2$ or $x< 2$

$\implies -2<x< 2$

Comment: $\lvert x \rvert \geq 0$ for all possible $x$

Comment: @dEmigOd could you show a solved explanation taking cases of $|2x|$ or point out where I made a mistake?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value

Comment: @dEmigOd I know what absolute value means, I just don't understand where I'm going wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|x| >r$ means $x >r$ OR $-x >r$. You are writing this as $x >r$ AND $-x >r$. For every real number $x$ we have $x <2$ or $x >-2$.

Comment: I changed it now, but still, I would have to take the intersection of $x<2$ and $x>-2$, right?

Comment: $\mathbb R =(-\infty, 2) \cup (-2,\infty)$.

Comment: OR correspond to union, not intersection.

Comment: ahh yes, I was making the mistake here, I'm still familiarising with modulus. Thanks, that was a silly mistake

Answer (score 0):

When you divide into cases, you have to consider what values of $x$ the different cases handle.

The case $2x>-4$ kicks in when $x$ is positive. And whenever this case is relevant, this inequality is true.

The case $-2x>-4$ kicks in when $x$ is negative. And for any negative $x$, this inequality is true.